# How can developer know how to import module with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lodash

How can developer know how to import module with webpack?

For example, I can use React Hooks like below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
useState()
// or
import React from 'react'
React.useState();
```

but, how can I know this?

I thought it can be related to 'node_modules/react/index.js', but it shows only below code.

```
module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
```

I assumed **module.exports** is like **export default** in ES module, but I can actually use both default import and named import with weback. I am very confused.

For another example, when I use lodash, the official document says like below.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Does it mean I should write like this

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

or like this?

```
import { _ } from 'lodash'
```

**How does webpack work with ES module and CommonJS internally?**

Comment: Read the documentation for a library, it usually tells you how to use it, including how to import it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to read the documentation and try to implement the specified method. Next, you can read the source of a particular module from Github and then figure out how it was exported. I think the documentation does provide enough info on how to import modules and use them.

And it is written like this -

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I read the documentation and source of React and lodash, but I am still not clear why I can write above way. What bout **import * as _ from 'lodash'**?

Comment: **_** is used to import the whole package. Though I don't know how module exports work exactly. But I know that you can import specific things which you require like -**import {map} from "lodash"** to decrease loading time and increase efficiency.